# What is the difference between "I don't think" and "I think....not"?

Tags: difference

> I don't think that she will pass the exam.

> I think that she will not pass the exam.

I would like to read answer, but not comment

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, they mean the same thing. However, the negated one is weaker.

Consider these statements:

- I don’t like this movie.
- I dislike this movie.

The first (negated) one allows the possibility of neither liking nor disliking the movie, so it is a weaker statement than the second.

This weakness in the negated form is still *felt* when there are only two choices, such as passing or failing an exam in your example, despite there being no neutral option to actually weaken it.

Comment: Right. The absence of X doesn't mean that anti-X is present. There are many things which I don't like, but which I also don't dislike - because I've never tried them.